# Laravel query for expired domain name notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just want to change this **MySql** query in to **Laravel** query builder:

```
SELECT * FROM domain_reg_infos WHERE d_expiryDate BETWEEN NOW() AND  NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

I have already search about it but could not find any solution. Please give me the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the laravel query you tested ?

Comment: $curren_time= Carbon::now();
$month = $dt->addDays(30);                                                 DB::select('select * from domain_reg_infos where BETWEEN $current_time AND $current_time + $month );

Comment: `DB::table('domain_reg_infos')->whereRaw('d_expiryDate between NOW() and NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //get today's date
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $now ) ) ); //add 1 month to $now

$domain_reg_infos = Domain_Reg_Info::whereBetween('expiryDate', array($now, $newdate))->get();
```

Comment: This is also good solution, but you have to be sure, that PHP and MySQL have the same datetime.

Comment: Yes, the MySQL `datetime` format is `Y-m-d H:i:s` you must adjust it to your format, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy man try that code.

```
 DB::table('domain_reg_infos')
    ->whereRaw('d_expiryDate between NOW() and NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may set current date and add 1 month with this at first.Then use this in your query like as :

```
$current_time = strtotime("2010.12.11");
$one_month_interval = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $current_time));
```

Then,

```
 $result = ModelClass::
        where('d_expiryDate ','>=',$current_time)
        ->where('d_expiryDate ','<=',$one_month_interval )
        ->get();
    return $result ;
```